# How to find out the item that fingers on in LIstview?

Tags: android, listview, event-listener

I have a listview and items in the listview. I start swiping my finger from top to bottom. First touch point of my finger is not on any listview item.(First touch starts out of listview on a different element on the screen). Then I swipe my finger on the listview items. In this point, which listeners I can call to find out on which item my finger is? every time my finger moves from one item to another the event will be triggered and I will know that my finger has moved on another item.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to find out the position of the item? Or the position on the screen( in px)?

Comment: I want to find out the item. but the onitemclicklistener does not fire when you touch first out of the listview and move on any item. because the screen goes on touch mode.first touch starts out of any itemof the listview and fingers swipe on the items. when the finger comes on a item I want to toast the item name.  and I keep swipe finger on the screen without lifting and when I change the item it will again toast the new item name..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to find out name of the item which you select/Touch.
For that you have implement setOnItemClickListener()

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
  String getSelectedItemOfList ;
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
          getSelectedItemOfList = (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)).toString();
    // Here you will get the selected item name in the listview.          
      }
   }        
 });
```

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Nope :) this does not work. I tried this. this works if you just click (first touch goes straight on an item). What I want to achieve is that the first touch goes on the somewhere else on the screen and then I swipe my finger on the items. basically the screen goes to touch mode and that OnitemClickListener does not fire..